# How do I find out the list of available cores before I launch a new VM using an ARM template

Tags: azure, virtual, azure-rm-template

How do I find out the list of available cores before I launch a new VM using an ARM template. I would like validate and see if the template will succeed in VM creation without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

To test your ARM Template you can use the following Powershell command:

```
Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment
```

To get the usage statistics use:

```
Get-AzureRmVMUsage -Location "northeurope"
```

To check available sizes:

```
Get-AzureRmVmSize -Location "northeurope"
```

Also, if you are looking for a way to do that with ARM Template, its not possible

Comment: sending the template through the /validate API (which is what Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment does will can most "availability" type issues in VMs (Quota, Availbility, Policy, etc).  Other RPs will change things like naming syntax, dns availability - so it's about the best test you can give before deployment.

Comment: actually, that validation is pretty crappy, it won't catch most of the errors that would happen at the runtime, it would only catch something reeaaaallly obvious, like missing parens @bmoore-msft

Comment: Well, many seem obvious after you see the error, but in any case the server side data suggests there's an awful lot of them caught...